# display: inline-block is not placing my div on the same line as the previous div

Tags: html, css

I have code which looks like the following:

```css
#DigiCertBlahBlah {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

#formLogin {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="images/logo.png" />
  <form name="formLogin" id="formLogin" method="post" action="Login.aspx">
    ...
  </form>
  <!-- Begin DigiCert site seal HTML and JavaScript -->
  <div id="DigiCertBlahBlah" data-language="en_US">
    <a href="http://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm">UCC SSL</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ...
  </script>
  <!-- End DigiCert site seal HTML and JavaScript -->
</div>
```

And I'm trying to get the DigiCert `<a>` tag to appear to the right of the `<form>` rather than on its own line.

However when I set them to `display: inline-block;` that does nothing; they still appear on separate lines.

How do I make the link appear to the right of the form? I can't do `float: right;` because the script tag contains code that inserts elements dynamically in the DOM, and that causes the form to jump around on the page.

Comment: use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and by the way on jsfiddle they appear on the same line

Comment: Can you add minimal working code to sort it out ?

Comment: What is the width of the form? If the form is very wide, wrapping will push the following div down below it, even if they're both inline-block.

Comment: I believe @kshetline has the answer here.

Comment: The width of the form is around 630px...

Comment: If you take a look at codepen for a minimal reproduction, you will see that the form is in-fact not-a-block-element and the link is next to it: https://codepen.io/pen/PoYyMmg -- I suggest you use your browser inspector and check the element by hovering it. It should show whats causing your form to go into full width (because that's what's happening over here). Maybe you have a right margin set to auto on the form as well, you'll see then.

Answer (score 2):

**what do you want exactly? please try this code**

```css
#DigiCertBlahBlah {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: super;
}

#formLogin {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<img src="https://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p450/wassimahmad/logo_zpsxkwqnisr.png" />
    <form name="formLogin" id="formLogin" method="post" action="Login.aspx">
        
    </form>
    <!-- Begin DigiCert site seal HTML and JavaScript -->
    <div id="DigiCertBlahBlah" data-language="en_US">
        <a href="http://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm">UCC SSL</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>
    <!-- End DigiCert site seal HTML and JavaScript -->
</div>
```

**You can replace on css

```css
#DigiCertBlahBlah {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**

**or this **

```css
#DigiCertBlahBlah {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
<style>
  .content {
    width: 100%
    max-width: 800px; // you can remove this if you want to use full width
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .div-row {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #DigiCertBlahBlah {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
  }

  #formLogin {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div class="content">
  <div class = "div-row">
    <img src="images/logo.png" />
  </div>
  <div class = "div-row">
    <form name="formLogin" id="formLogin" method="post" action="Login.aspx">
        ...
    </form>
    <!-- Begin DigiCert site seal HTML and JavaScript -->
    <div id="DigiCertBlahBlah" data-language="en_US">
        <a href="http://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm">UCC SSL</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
    </script>
    <!-- End DigiCert site seal HTML and JavaScript -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this is a legacy app and I'm not sure if `calc` is supported on all browsers running this app... Thanks though! :)

Comment: If calc not works, please set specific width for them (#DigiCertBlahBlah, #formLogin)////  :)