# How Can I make this specific Layout in HTML ? Text Wrapped in Right Hand Corner / Body Below

Tags: html, css, image, layout

Does anyone happen to know how to create a layout similar to this in HTML? I am trying to make a "profile" based layout where it displays a picture where the person's name is directly in the right corner and a description is under the header, yet still to the right of the image. Here is a picture of what I am trying to create along with what I have tried to do.

[image]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.topright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h2>Image Text</h2>
  <p>Add some text to an image in the top right corner:</p>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="1000" height="300">
    <div class="topright">NAME HERE </div>
    Sample text goes here
  </div>

</body>
```

The problem with my code above is that the 'NAME HERE' message appears inside of the image and the sample text is below the image. I would prefer for them to both be on the right of the image. I have taken a simple approach to it, but if anyone knows how to incorporate it using CSS or another method, it would be appreciate it.

Comment: see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776067/display-inline-block-is-not-placing-my-div-on-the-same-line-as-the-previous-div/57776889#57776889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin with something like this, I have made slightly modification to html.

> 1. You can use `flex` for the `container` class that will make the content to flow in `row`.
> 2. you need the right content to be in column so add `flex` and `direction` property to `.topright{...}` this will give you content one below the other.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.topright {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 15px;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h2>Image Text</h2>
  <p>Add some text to an image in the top right corner:</p>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="Cinque Terre" width="300" height="300">
    <div class="topright">NAME HERE
      <div class="text">
        What is Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
        book it has? Easily generate Lorem Ipsum placeholder text in any number of characters, words sentences or paragraphs. Learn about the origins of the passage </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .img{
            width:250px;
            height:250px;
        }
        h1{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .text{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 330px;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }
        p{
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <image class="img" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg"></image>
    <div class='text'>
        <h1>NAME HERE</h1>
        <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
            commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
            dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add img to div tag and provide witdth to both divs.

```
    .container {
       position: relative;
    }

    .topright {
      top:0;
      margin-left:20px;
      position:absolute;
      font-size: 18px;
   }
   .d-block{
    dispaly:block;
   }
   img{width:100%}

  .w-50{
    width:48%;
    display:inline-block
   }

 <div class="container">
<div class="w-50">
    <img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" >
</div>
<div class="topright w-50">
    <p class="d-block">NAME HERE</p> 
    <p class="d-block">Sample text goes here</p>
</div>
```